# Adding 25% to Column in Excel

Tags: arrays, regex, if-statement, google-sheets, percentage

I have a CSV file that I want to adjust pricing.
How would I add 25% to the price column. It has 1700 products on it so doing it by hand would take to long.

The column looks like this:

Price
0
69.9875
169.9875
[FIXED]69.9875
[FIXED]169.9875

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRXZ50t4AWRTOAQUYRFKlAsWh_BWJs5kfjvyq79xSvA/edit?usp=sharing

I can get it to change the numbers but the cells with text it wont change.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If it always says `[FIXED]`, do `mid(cell,8,7)*1.25`?

Comment: How do I implement that?

Comment: This is the spreadsheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRXZ50t4AWRTOAQUYRFKlAsWh_BWJs5kfjvyq79xSvA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: do you want to add 25% even  to 0?

Comment: @player0 25% of 0 is still 0...

Comment: @findwindow that's true, at least in this universe

Comment: No just 25% off to the [FIXED] Items.

Comment: `How would I add 25%` then `just 25% off`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "(\[.+\])\d+(?:.\d+)?"))&
 (REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "\d+(?:.\d+)?")+
  REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "\d+(?:.\d+)?")*0.25)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

> No just 25% off to the [FIXED] Items

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A&"", "(\[.+\])\d+(?:.\d+)?"), 
 IFERROR(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "(\[.+\])\d+(?:.\d+)?"))&
 (REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "\d+(?:.\d+)?")+
  REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "\d+(?:.\d+)?")*0.25)), A2:A))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FOLml0vJli0FcK8LjSIZ_04EHkeMXjX3aLHUbIcf8K8/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Where do I enter this to get my entire spreadsheet.

Comment: @GlennKline here is how you use the formula: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FOLml0vJli0FcK8LjSIZ_04EHkeMXjX3aLHUbIcf8K8/edit#gid=0

Comment: I cannot get this to work in my Product CSV sheet. This is my CSV. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRXZ50t4AWRTOAQUYRFKlAsWh_BWJs5kfjvyq79xSvA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @GlennKline see K2: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRXZ50t4AWRTOAQUYRFKlAsWh_BWJs5kfjvyq79xSvA/edit#gid=1642367247

Comment: Thanks for putting that in my products but its still showing me the normal price.

Comment: @GlennKline as you said: "No just 25% off to the [FIXED] Items" so this formula adds 25% only to those cells that contain FIXED. if you want to add 25% to all numbers in column use the first formula from the answer